# Magento2 - language pack installation doesn't work

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, localisation, language-package

I installed fresh Magento 2.1.0 installation.

After the installation completed, I checked that everything works good.

Now I want to change the language of the store to my language (Hebrew)

I downloaded the language pack files from here https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2/he

And use this guide:
http://www.vanderboon.net/wiki/Install_Magento_Crowdin_Translation with the following command lines:

```
 cd /var/www/html
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy he_IL
 php bin/magento indexer:reindex
 php bin/magento cache:clean
 php bin/magento cache:flush
 chown -R www-data. .
 find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

In the admin panel Stores -> System -> Configuration -> General -> General -> Locale Options -> Change Local to Hebrew and save.

Also in the right side -> Account settings (admin) -> Change Inteface Locale to Hebrew and save.

I don't see any change in the store or in admin panel.

What I did wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install it with the official guide of magento with the command

```
magento i18n:pack [-m|--mode={merge|replace}] [-d|--allow-duplicates] <source> <locale>
```

More details you can find here

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-pack

Answer (score 1):

Check the generated he_IL.csv file. It must be having no translation in Hebrew language. If it is so, you need to either translate the texts or download from somewhere and replace the previous file with this csv.

May be this will work for you: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mageplaza/magento-2-hebrew-language-pack/master/he_IL.csv